# jQuery selector by data-id - Select many ids from an array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

On a modal form that displays a list of items, I want to mark the ones that are already selected. Is there a way to select several elements at once providing an array of ids?

Example:

```
$('.searchable').find('[role~=item]')
```

returns

```
<tr role=​"item character" data-id=​"1">​…​</tr>​
<tr role=​"item character" data-id=​"2">​…​</tr>​
<tr role=​"item character" data-id=​"3">​…​</tr>​
<tr role=​"item character" data-id=​"4">​…​</tr>​
```

But i want to mark the items that are already selected adding them a "selected" class. I got the selected items in an array. Example: array = [1,3]

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
$('.searchable').find('[role~=item][data-id=array')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Do you want to select on multiple attribute values? Or do you want to select on a class+attribute value? Or something else? Or - ah! - do you want to do a select on attribute values that contain one of the elements in an array?

Comment: @AndersHolmström I want to add the class ".selected" to all the items that have the attribute data-id equal to an element of the array. In this case, to the first and third item

Comment: Ah. Well there's no way to do that with a single select statement as far as I know - you'll have to loop through the array in some way. See the answers below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through array by using each and perform operation in each element in array,

```
 jQuery.each(array, function(i, item) {
     $(item).data("id");  
 };
```

or you cna try some thing like this,

```
var filtered = $('.searchable').find(function(){
   if(array.indexOf(this.val(), 0)
        return $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Array = [1,3], 
    elems;

$.each(Array, function(i,e) {
    elems.add( $('[role~=item][data-id="'+e+'"]', '.searchable') );
});

elems.addClass('highlight');
```